# difference between float and double data type

Tags: c#, var

How can a float variable be stored in a double variable?

How to remove the compiler error in the following command?

```cs
float numb;
numb = 22.54;
```

Comment: You can denote a float literal by appending an "F": `numb = 22.54F;`

Comment: What did you find when you researched that compiler error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main differences in float and double. Those are size and precision.

Float - 7 digits of precision(32 bit) and 4 bytes
Ex:- 0.1234567

Double- 15 digits of precision (64 bit) and 8 bytes
Ex:- 0.123456789123456

You can store float value in a double variable like this

```
double numb;
float numb2 = 22.5F;
numb = numb2;

output -> 22.5
```

Comment: `You can store float variable in a double variable like this`, it's not a `double` type, it's a `float`.... I believe you mean to say, `you can store a double in a float variable...`...

Comment: Yes my bad. I fixed the answer.